# How to use mermaid syntax in Quarto text does not fit in diagram box

Tags: r, quarto, mermaid

I am trying to use mermaid library in Quarto however the text in the boxes do not fit - they cut off the last letter or two.

Can anyone provide a solution?

I have already checked out two open questions below but they are different than my question

[Mermaid diagram in Quarto/Rmarkdown: narrow and blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73635448/mermaid-diagram-in-quarto-rmarkdown-narrow-and-blurry)

[How to prevent mermaid flow charts overflowing in quarto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73684948/how-to-prevent-mermaid-flow-charts-overflowing-in-quarto)

Code below:

````
---
format: revealjs
---


## Example

Blah Blah


```{mermaid}
flowchart LR
A[real time insights] --> B{Classification}
B --> C[Threat]
B --> D[Opportunity]
C --> E[Defend Value]
D --> F[Capture Value]
```
````

Comment: it is a reveal.js document issue, works find in html document

Comment: hi @JulienColomb! thanks for the response. Sorry, I understand your response to mean that this is a known documented issue? or how do I understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't solve the issue but just simply adding some spaces (1-3) after your text will move the border of the box so that your text isn't cut off.